# How To Override the “Back” button in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

On my Home widget, when user taps system back button, I want to show a confirmation dialog asking "Do you want to exit the App?"

I don't understand how I should override or handle the system back button.

Answer (score 364, accepted):

You can use [`WillPopScope`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html) to achieve this.

Example:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key, this.title}) :super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  Future<bool> _onWillPop() async {
    return (await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(
        title: new Text('Are you sure?'),
        content: new Text('Do you want to exit an App'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
            child: new Text('No'),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
            child: new Text('Yes'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )) ?? false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _onWillPop,
      child: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Home Page"),
        ),
        body: new Center(
          child: new Text("Home Page"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The `??-operator` checks for `null`, see [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#operators). This is important because if you click outside the dialog, showDialog returns `null` and in this case false is returned.

Comment: Can we change the icon too of the back button?

Comment: Yes, of course. There is property `leading` that the `AppBar` takes. You can specify an `IconButton` with what every icon you want or any other widgets too.

Comment: Thanks but I also figured that out by my own. We have limited space in `leading` property, so we can't really use any widget. It should be generally an `IconButton` that you wanna use.

Comment: But this will not override the physical device back button? How to detect device back button?

Comment: Sorry, I think it does. You mean it only works with flutter back button? I see it works with hard and soft back buttons too.

Comment: Can somebody please explain me what does the `?? false` code at the very end of the `_onWillPop` method does?

Comment: @SaloGala The `varvalue ?? false` instruction tells the compiler to return false if the **varvalue** is null

Comment: Why async await is used here ?

Comment: on yes TextButton pressed, it should be SystemNavigator.pop(); instead of Navigator.of(context).pop(true)

Comment: 'WillPopScope' is deprecated and shouldn't be used.