# how to handle switch page logic on back press in flutter

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter, onbackpressed

I am new to flutter, I handed back press event by onWillPop () to show alert dialog. But I need to show the alert dialog for home page only (like Are you want to exit?). In the code I have a type like current page if the current page is home, then only show Alert dialog or otherwise switch to home page.

**Code**

```
if(currentType == Home)
{
    showExitDialog();
}
else
{
   switchToHome();
}
```

Where can i handle this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set custom `leading` property on your app bar.

The default value is to go back one page, so if you dont set nothing, back arrow will be there and it will do `Navigator.of(context).maybePop();`

From Navigator docs

> If this is null and [automaticallyImplyLeading] is set to true, the [AppBar] will imply an appropriate widget. For example, if the [AppBar] is in a [Scaffold] that also has a [Drawer], the [Scaffold] will fill this widget with an [IconButton] that opens the drawer (using [Icons.menu]). If there's no [Drawer] and the parent [Navigator] can go back, the [AppBar] will use a [BackButton] that calls [Navigator.maybePop].

But if you want to override it do this

on your home page

```
  appBar: AppBar(
    leading: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),onPressed: (){
      exitTheApp();
    },),
  ),
```

on your other AppBars

```
  appBar: AppBar(
    leading: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.home),onPressed: (){
      showHomePage();
    },),
  ),
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but if user click mobile default back button then how to handle ?

Comment: you can use WillPopScope. check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49356664/how-to-override-the-back-button-in-flutter