# How to move backward in PageView when press back button [Flutter]

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to move backward when press the back button using a pageView, I read about the WillPopScope component, but I am not pushing/poping another screens. I am just moving in diferent pages on the pageView.

Any clue how to do that?

Best regards.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yep, you can achieve so using `WillPopScope`. Not sure if this is optimal though, but it works perfectly with me; keep in mind that I wanted the back button to work from the one of the pages to the one before it, and not over all pages, but I am sure the solution applies.

In the page, I surrounded everything with `WillPopScope` like this

```
return new WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () => Future.sync(onWillPop),
  child: // Whatever your page was
```

Now, you will have to define the proc `onWillPop`, and it is like this in my case

```
bool onWillPop() {
  _controller.previousPage(
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
    curve: Curves.linear,
  );
  return false;
}
```

In my case, this never fails as it is only used in one of the views, and only one.

**In your case**, you may wanna condition like this:

```
bool onWillPop() {
  if (_controller.page.round() == _controller.initialPage)
    return true;
  else {
    _controller.previousPage(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      curve: Curves.linear,
    );
    return false;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps. For reference on overriding the back button in general, refer to this [other StackOverFlowAnswer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49356664/how-to-override-the-back-button-in-flutter)

***EDIT***: Added a return value to my onWillPop to remove dart warning.

Comment: Hey I followed your answer. But I am having trouble, When I implement this in one of my PageView's page than other pages also behave similarly. I just want back from a single page not from other page.

Comment: Each page has its own number, so if you want to enable this for one page alone, you can condition the controller's `page` attribute to be equal to yours before executing `previousPage` method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use PageController to control your PageView.

```
    PageController _pageController;
```

You can use the PageController got to the previous page:

```
    _pageController.previousPage(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.linear);
```

Or to go to the initial page:

```
     _pageController.jumpToPage(_pageController.initialPage);
```

Comment: Yeah, I know I can move forward or backward in the PageView using a button or something like that, but when I press the back button on the phone the app close, because the navigator **pop** the current view, but I want to move backward in the pageview instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write the onWillPop() like this:

```
if (_controller.page.round() == _controller.initialPage) {
      return true;
    } else {
      _controller.previousPage(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        curve: Curves.linear,
      );
      return false;
    }
```

So it always return a bool.