# how to disable phone back press in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am new to Flutter development. Can anyone share me how to disable the back press in `flutter`?

In Android, we can use `onbackpressed` method.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  // super.onBackPressed(); commented this line in order to disable back press
  //Write your code here
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Back press disabled!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

In `flutter` how it possible to do?

Comment: take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49356664/how-to-override-the-back-button-in-flutter

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Wrap your widget inside `WillPopScope` and return a false `Future` in the `onWillPop` property

```
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () => Future.value(false),
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text("Home Page"),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: const Text("Home Page"),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
```

Refer to this documentation: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html

Comment: Is it just for back button or home button and recent activity button too?

Comment: we can't block the home button

Comment: Can we use event for home button? For example if click home button will need password

Comment: Is there an easy way to disable it for the whole app? Or do I have to wrap every screen with WillPopScope

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use `WillPopScope` but here's an alternative method if for some reason you don't want to or can't use the `WillPopScope` widget.

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  ModalRoute<dynamic> _route;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    _route?.removeScopedWillPopCallback(_onWillPop);
    _route = ModalRoute.of(context);
    _route?.addScopedWillPopCallback(_onWillPop);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _route?.removeScopedWillPopCallback(_onWillPop);
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<bool> _onWillPop() => Future.value(false);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Container();
}
```

Comment: An explanation would have been great.

Comment: @OjonugwaJudeOchalifu I can't remember exactly why I posted this or why one would prefer this solution over just using WillPopScope. It's almost exactly what WillPopScope does. Just look at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/will_pop_scope.dart and also check the API docs for WillPopScope and ModalRoute for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

just set automaticallyImplyLeading: false,under appbar property