# using the system back button from flutter driver

Tags: testing, flutter, integration-testing, flutter-test, flutterdriver

How can I use the system back button in an integration test?

So I'm using flutter and am writing integration tests, in most circumstances I can use the AppBar navigation, finding it by tool tip looks like this :

```
driver.tap(find.byTooltip('Back'));
```

But one of my tests opens a web page, after this opens I need to carry on with my tests which means I need to press the system back button, is this possible?

many thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have `adb` installed on your machine, you can run a command to perform the backpress using a keyevent:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
```

```dart
await Process.run(
  'adb', 
  <String>['shell', 'input', 'keyevent', 'KEYCODE_BACK'], 
  runInShell: true,
);
```

Comment: what about iPhones? 
how can we press the home button etc.. programmatically

Comment: iPhone's home button is not a back button, it directs the user to the device home. If you want to test the equivalent of a backpress on iOS you may want to try a drag from right to left.

Comment: is there any way to press the Home screen on iPhone programmatically?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this can help you

```
 await device.shellExec('input', <String>['keyevent', 'KEYCODE_BACK']);
```

Found in one of the official flutter driver tests [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/ec1a0150458dd773527e060b0c3659699d542be5/dev/devicelab/bin/tasks/flutter_gallery__back_button_memory.dart#L37)

Comment: Seems that the device.shellExec depends on the flutter_devicelab which is only available within the framework

Answer (score -3):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49356664/how-to-override-the-back-button-in-flutter) link. In short, you'll need to use `WillPopScope` class that handles device back button with callbacks.

Comment: not applicable from flutter driver, im aware of willPopScope and its usage but thank you