# Back button doesn't close the app from home page

Tags: android, flutter

I have a flutter app in which when opened it opens the splash screen and then the home page.

when I'm in the home page and I click Android's back button nothing happens since I used this code:

```
new WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async => false,
    child:Directionality(
        textDirection: direction,
        child:...
   )
)
```

but I want the application to exit if  I clicked the back button in Android from the home page.

is there's a way to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Override the “Back” button in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49356664/how-to-override-the-back-button-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is intended behaviour since `WillPopScope` overrides the navigation.

You should implement the navigation yourself

example:

```
Future<bool> _exitApp(BuildContext context) {
  return showDialog(
        context: context,
        child: new AlertDialog(
          title: new Text('Do you want to exit this application?'),
          content: new Text('We hate to see you leave...'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new FlatButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
              child: new Text('No'),
            ),
            new FlatButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
              child: new Text('Yes'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ) ??
      false;
}
```

```
new WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async => _exitApp(context),
    child:Directionality(
        textDirection: direction,
        child:...
   )
)
```

[Reference](https://codingwithjoe.com/flutter-navigation-how-to-prevent-navigation/).

**EDIT** to exit the app you can add `import 'dart:io';` abd use `exit(0)` function.

Comment: i don't need the dialog .. i want to close the app on click .. tried to just put it like this but it didn't work :     onWillPop: () async => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),

Comment: `Navigator.of(context).pop()` have you tried with this on backpressed ?

Comment: it will display a black screen if i clicked on back

Comment: try `exit(0)` instead on `Navigator.of(context).pop()`

Comment: i got this error: The method 'exit' isn't defined for the class 'MainPageState'.

Comment: You need to add `import 'dart:io';`

Comment: can you add this to your answer please so i can accept it