# How to pop bottom modal sheet when keyboard is hidden?

Tags: flutter, bottom-sheet

I want to pop my bottom modal sheet when my keyboard is hidden. But currently when I press back button keyboard gets hidden but bottom modal sheet remains opened.

I tried using package *flutter_keyboard_visibility* to detect if the keyboard is hidden and tried to pop the bottom navigation bar. But now when do that and press outside barrier to dismiss, there are two calls to Navigator.pop(context) method. One after hiding the keyboard and another built-in pop by the bottom modal sheet.

Can anyone help me find out how to achieve this?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would do it the following way:

a) Return `WillPopScope` inside the `Widget build method`

b) As a `callback` for WillPopScope I will `Navigator.pop(context)`

You can also try the [**keyboard_visiblity**](https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_visibility) plugin. This will provide you a callback easily.

Comment: I already tried keyboard_visibility package, as described in question it pops context twice. I would really appreciate if you could provide code sample with WillPopScope, seems like i could not figure out how to implement it. Thanks

Comment: @BluBox Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49356664/how-to-override-the-back-button-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `setState(() {});` ?

it will also helps for updating the state of screen

Comment: I use Provider for my state management. And I dont think it's a state management issue. Thanks

Comment: @BluBox if my answer helps you then feel free to accept :)