# Do something before page pop

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to run some script before exiting a page?
Something like: showing a dialog confirming getting out of page

sorry for bad english in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, found the answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49356664/how-to-override-the-back-button-in-flutter)
using `WillPopScope`