# How to dismissed showDialog with backBoutton?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a showDialog called inside FloatingActionButton, I want to dismiss the showDialog when the back button is clicked, **but it is returned to the previous page without dismiss**

MyCode

```
 FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () async {
        
            await showDialog(
              context: context,
              // useRootNavigator: false,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return AlertDialog(
                  title: Text("Dialog"),
........)
```

Comment: You mean the back button on a physical android device?

Comment: yes............

Comment: @krumpli any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Because you are passing the wrong context of the page. I had the same issue today i solved it by doing

```
 FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () async {
    
        await showDialog(
          context: context,
          // useRootNavigator: false,
          builder: (BuildContext dialogContext) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text("Dialog"),
........)
```

and then i popped the dialog with the `dialogContext`

```
Navigator.of(dialogContext).pop();
```

Comment: how to detect the back button pressed ?

Comment: backButton wont close dialog, instead you can give a button that closes the dialog.

Comment: If you want to detect physical back button pressed than you can you WillPopScope

Comment: You can detect the back button pressed with WillPopScope.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49356916/10659482

Comment: That's exactly what i said. Thanks Akif for the link

Comment: I already tried to wrap my ALertDialog with _onWillPop butck doesnt work

Comment: The WillPopScope has to wrap all Scaffold on your page, not only the AlertDialog widget.

Comment: yes but there is no way to dismiss a poppo with backButton ?

Comment: No! There is no way to dismiss popup with BackButton.