# Flutter Container on Pressed who show a big container

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I'm a beginner and I would like to create a button/container who have only a color and on pressed of this container it show a container more big on the center who have some information, like image and text.

And when I go back return a small container.

Like in this video at the minutes 2:07 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E-gi8xPBuNo

Comment: I think you want to create something like this https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-deep-dive-into-hero-widgets-in-flutter-d34f441eb026

Comment: Yes but i would like in the same page of container and not in another screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `BottomSheet` is what you are looking for https://punitd.dev/static/0529ed371ac3fe7808b3392ea603047c/fbf08/image_2.png

and for the "small container" (the one that says "Measurement saved", right?) you could try using a `SnackBar`
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHTZ3.png

Good luck with your project,
-Cedric

Comment: Thank you so much Cedric and it is the answer I was looking for 

Answer (score 0):

You can try to override on back button pressed function using WillPopScope widget.
Refer this [stackOverFlow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49356664/how-to-override-the-back-button-in-flutter)